# Increase ground clearance of hyundai accent 2012

Tags: car, hyundai, clearance

I have a Hyundai Accent car - 2012 model. Since the roads in my country are not so smooth, I am having a tough time taking it around.

Is it possible to increase the ground clearance for my car, even if by a few inches?

Comment: Perhaps you should consider a different vehicle, you know what the roads are like?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, you can get [spacer kits](https://www.spaccer.com/en_US/makes-and-models/hyundai/accent-i-stufenheck.html) to raise the ground clearance of the car.

That said there will be affects on the handling - and possibly increased wear on some suspension components as it will effect the geometry significantly in ways that the original designers and engineers of the car will likely not have planned for so I can't say for sure how well it will work.

This will also do nothing to strengthen the suspension components to handle the increased level of impacts and work the suspension and other components will be doing on such terrain.

Ultimately the Accent is a car that's designed with driving on relatively smooth tarmac/asphalt as it's primary operating mode so ultimately you're using it for something it's not made for and you may be better off considering a swap to something designed to handle more rugged terrain.

Answer (score 0):

Raising the suspension is going to adversely affect your wheel alignment.  Perhaps you might consider a larger tire.  Such as a higher first pair of numbers,. If your tire is a 165-75/ 14.   Look for a 175-90/14....it's a little bigger but not much, but the 90 number is the key.  The 75 in the first size is the percent of how high the tire is in relation to it's width...75 % as high as it is wide.  The 90 on the second tire is 90% as high as it is wide.  So the 165 tire will be almost 124 mm off the rim and the 90 tire would be 157 mm off the rim, which would give you about a bit less than one inch in height.  You can also go to a taller wheel such as from a 14 to a 15 or even a 16.  You can also look at the overall advertised tire height, that information should be available by either the manufacturer or the tire store that sells them.  Hope this helps.